# What FPS should I use for 59.94 footage slowed down?

Tags: editing, davinci-resolve, fps

What I'm doing seems to work but reading conflicting things online has me confused.

Right now things I upload go to YouTube or Vimeo.

I shoot 29.976 or 59.94 FPS and slow them down to 23.976 in Davinci Resolve clip attributes. (I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be using 24FPS right?)

I create my timelines as 23.976, do my editing and color grading, then should I deliver to 24 FPS or 23.976 FPS?

I'm currently doing 23.976 but I've read other advice to to use 24 but I couldn't understand why.

What framerate should I use for uploading to the web? What goes right/wrong depending on my choice?

Answer (score 0):

The slight difference between the round number (30) and the other framerate (29.97) is due to historical reasons, where the signal of a black and white video was 30fps but when introducing the color data to the signal, and due they needed to maintain the parameters of the transmission, they reduced the framerate a bit so they had some space to integrate it.

If your video is not going to be broadcasted, rounding numbers just makes life easier. (I am not sure if the broadcast by radiowaves spec has changed now that almost all signals are digital)

---

As you already edited the project at 23.97, you should export at the same framerate. In theory, if you change the export to 24, you will have a duplicate frame every, let's say every 1000 frames to compensate for the gap.

When the video is delivered digitally, in theory, there is no need for FPS conversion. You can have a video with strange numbers, like 15Fps or 17.5...

I say in theory because I have not made extensive tests. But when you see the stats on a youtube video, for example, as far as I can tell, it uses round numbers.

[image]

Probably is because everyone is actually using round numbers, or the text on the stats is simply rounding them.

Another possible thing to consider, between 29.97 and 30, is that most monitors have a refresh rate of 60hz so, it could be an argument to round numbers too. But the difference is so small that probably no one will notice.

For your next project, you can choose 24fps (or 30 and 60) and simplify your life.